# Push notification doesn't update immediately

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working with push notification on iOS 8+. I try to update UIUserNotificationSettings values and get it back to compare, but it does not the same. Could someone help me resolve/explain this issue for me. Many thank.

Here is my code:

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
        NSLog(@"Before register: %u", types);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

UIUserNotificationSettings* currentSeting =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
NSLog(@"After register: %u", currentSeting.types);
```

Here is output console:

```
Before register: 6
After register: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking it in the `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` delegate method like this:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings*)notificationSettings
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings* currentSeting =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
}
```

Comment: currentSeting is still 0

Comment: make sure push notifications are turned 'ON' for your app in your device's settings just in case.

Comment: Here is the official documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationSettings_class/index.html